# Bash script to detect uploaded files triggers many times for one file

Tags: bash, shell-script, inotify

I have a simple bash script setup that uses the built-in inotify daemon running CentOS 6.6. The script will simply echo the file that is upload to a specific directory. The script works but it echos out the same filename over 100 times. I can't seem to figure out why it would do that.

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/inotifywait -e create,delete,modify,move -mrq --format %f /home/imgthe/public_html/run/thumbs --excludei sess_* | 
while read INPUT
do
    FILENAME=$INPUT

    DATE='date'

    echo $FILENAME
    printf $INPUT >> sku.txt
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `modify` attribute to `inotifywait` will notify you whenever the file is modified (i.e. written to). I suggest that you might prefer to replace `create` and `modify` with `close_write`.

Comment: Perfect. That did the trick. Thanks so much!!!!!!